# Mapping AWS instances to GC instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Let's say I want to deploy an instance on google cloud engine instead of AWS EC2.

According to the description I found on AWS website, an instance is defined by its CPU, Memory, storage and networking. And I found a mapping between EC2 and GCE instances on the GC website. However, the corresponding instances have very different CPU and Memory. Also, as it's possible to customize machine type on GCE, isn't it more adequate to just custom all my machines to give them the exact same characteristics as the equivalent instances with AWS ?

Comment: I believe it is quite correct to say a Compute Engine (GCP VM) is defined by its CPU, memory, storage and networking.  In addition, there will be the OS deployed on the boot disk.  If you have an AWS EC2 instance, identify its specs and then map those to the equivalent on GCP.  GCP provides finer grained customization beyond the T-Shirt sizes provided by AWS.  You can thus tweak your configurations for finer grained (more or less) resources at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're referring to this page:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/compute

Which is where the Google docs cover some terminology and equivalency between the two offerings. Note that where it's talking on that page around instance mapping, it isn't intended to be a 1:1 mapping of CPU/RAM/etc. It's just talking about general buckets and what they're named. So e.g. t2.micro vs. f1-micro, etc. I don't believe the intention is that those are necessarily the same machine configurations, but more that the bucket of "instance type" like "standard", "high memory", "high CPU", etc" and how the names line up with the general category between the two companies.

As Kolban mentioned in his comment, yes, GCE instances can just be configured specifically with RAM/CPU numbers rather than relying on the tier to make it equivalent to what you need.

One other piece, is that you'll also likely want to customize the storage. Out of the box there's limited options around storage for an instance, but if you (in the creation) go look at the options to add storage disk, it gives you the option of things like adding local SSDs, or persistent disks to the instance which allows you to tune it to be more specifically aligned with whatever you're coming from.